# Getting the difference in minutes between two date columns

Tags: shell

I have a file which contain two columns(start date time and end date time) I want to calculate the difference between these dates(in Mins). and store the difference in another column.

Source File

```
20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34
```

Output File

```
20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34|73
```

Can anyone help on this. Any help is appreciated.

Please tell me what is the problem in below command

```
echo "20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34"|awk -F'|' '{"date -d "$1" +%s"|getline d1;"date -d "$2" +%s"|getline d2;print $1"|"$2"|"d2-d1}'
```

I am getting below error while executing the command

```
sh: +%s: command not found
```

Please help me !!

Comment: tried anything so far so that people can pitch in?

Comment: This can help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636 . So `date1=$(date -d "20121224 22:16:10" "+%s")`, same for date2 and then substract.

Answer (score 1):

your example output is **not** correct.

```
20121224 23:03:34
20121224 22:16:10
```

tell me why the diff (in min) is 73? it should be anyway less than 60!

here is an awk oneliner working for your problem:

```
awk -F'|' -v q='"' '{"date -d"q $1 q" +%s"|getline d1;"date -d"q $2 q" +%s"|getline d2;print $0"|"(d2-d1)/60}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34"|awk -F'|' -v q='"' '{"date -d"q $1 q" +%s"|getline d1;"date -d"q $2 q" +%s"|getline d2;print $0"|"(d2-d1)/60}'
20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34|47.4
```

Comment: Thanks Kent for your response.... But I am getting below error to using your example command
sh: +%s: command not found

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime                   qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S',
);

open(FILE,"<your_file_name_with_path>");

while(<FILE>)
{
my @arr=split /|/,$_;
difference_mins $arr[0] $arr[1]

}

sub difference_mins
{
my ($istart,$istop)=($_[0],$_[1]);
my $start = $format->parse_datetime( $_[0] );
my $stop  = $format->parse_datetime( $_[1] );

$_->set_time_zone('local') for $start, $stop;
print "$istart | $istop | ";
print( $start->delta_ms($stop)->in_units('minutes'), "\n" );
}
```

- *NOTE: This is not tested though.*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '
    function parse_date(d) {
        gsub(/:/, " ", d)
        return mktime(substr(d,1,4) " " substr(d,5,2) " " substr(d,7))
    }
    {
        diff = int((parse_date($1) - parse_date($2)) / 60)
        diff *= (diff < 0) ? -1 : 1   # awk is missing abs()
        print $0, diff
    }
' << END
20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34
END
```

```
20121224 22:16:10|20121224 23:03:34|47
```